# Github action reusable workflow

Tags: github-actions

I am calling a reusable workflow from another repository.

Basically; Build frontend -> reusable workflow with e2e testing

However, when I'm calling the reusable workflow, it says that "no tests found". The frontend repo calls the reusable workflow like this:

```
e2e_tests:
  needs: publish_frontend
  name: Run e2e tests
  uses: org/repo/.github/workflows/deploy_tests.yml@master
  secrets: inherit
```

And in my e2e-test, I checkout:

```
steps:
 - name: Checkout
   uses: actions/checkout@v2
   with: 
     token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT || github.token}}
     repository: org/e2e-repo
     ref: master
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show the workflow that is calling this one. Are you doing a checkout there?

Comment: Please also show how you run the tests along with relevant logs.

Comment: So I get an error saying: repository e2e not found.

Comment: As I said, show **how** you run the test (YAML steps) along with **relevant** logs not just one error message.

Comment: It's basically this. It cannot checkout the repo. Both repos are private, but within the same organization.

Comment: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/16838 This is currently planned for support GP in Oct-Dec 2022